# Highcharts stocks - Scale candlesticks serie only

Tags: highcharts, tradingview-api

i have two series to display (one is a candlestick and the other is a simple line) and i want the chart scale only based on the candlestick series.

On the Tradingview website [this option](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Scaling_Options) is:

> Scale Series Only
>
> This option is for when there are studies or indicators overlaid onto the main chart window. When this option is active, the axis will scale according to the data series (price) alone. The values and coordinates of any active indicators will not be factored into the scaling of the axis.

My code is:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('chart-container', {
   series: [
          {
               type: 'candlestick',
               data: data.ohlc,
          },
          {
               data: data.otherLine,
          },
    ]
    ...
```

**Is it possible to do this with highchart?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highstock doesn't offer a property that'll do it automatically.

It can be done manually: find the lowest & the highest y value in your data and assign them to `yAxis.min` &  `yAxis.max` options:

```
yAxis: {
  min: 380,
  max: 600
},
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/puzxykva/

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/